# Social buttons platforms for a website

Tags: button, share

I'm just done with my research of social sharing platforms and cant decide which one to use. So, what I understand by now:

ShareThis - is a perfect website which provides many buttons, but these buttons are ugly and absent counters except the standart ones (which are the ugliest ones)

AddThis - provedes more beautiful buttons and one counter for all of them. However, the counter works whenever you click the button and doesnt check wheather you complete sharing or not... so it is inacurate.

Share42 - the best tool in my opinion, because it allows you to use your own images for the buttons + it has great counters for every button connected directly to its sevice. The problem with Share42 is that it doesnt attach the thumbnail icon to the buttons (I tried og:image, link, different propertes of images on the page... it just doesnt work).. and without an image the "share" link looses 90% of its effect.

So, my questions to you, is it possible to use your own images for AddThis or ShareThis (may be by css or by some additional script...) or how to make Share42 buttons to show the thumbnail?

Or may be you can recommend me a different service. All I want is a pannel of flat share buttons with an accurate counter or counters.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: afaik , add this support your own image, please refer to this link http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381236-custom-buttons#.UaVy3dJwze4

Comment: wow, thank you, can you post it as an anwer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, add this support your own image , you could refer to this link >

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381236-custom-buttons#.UaV2htJwze5

and also you could Customize the Third Party Buttons also :

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381237-third-party-buttons#.UaV2udJwze4

just, lil bit custumization on its css :)

Answer (score 4):

I built a generator for this very thing.

http://sharebuttongenerator.aakilfernandes.com/